# Check if user exists in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to create a users database in Cloud Firestore, with the email as the unique ID for each user. The users should be in a `collection`, and each user is a `document`.

This is how I check if the user exists in the login activity:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                            final DocumentReference userRef = db.collection("users").document(email);
                            userRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();

                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, task.getResult().toString(),
                                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        if (document != null) {
                                            //The user exists...
                                        }


                                        else {
                                            //The user doesn't exist...
                                           }

                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                        connectionErrorActivity();

                                }
                            });
```

The database is empty, as you can see:

[image]

**My problem is, that `document` is never null, even tough the database is empty.** The `toast` shows that the string value of `document` is: `COM.GOOGLE.FIREBASE.FIRESTORE.DOCUMENTSNAPSHOT@8ED6B96`.

Is this the correct way to do this? What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of this `Task` is a `DocumentSnapshot`. Whether or not the underlying document actually exists is available via the [`exists`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#exists()) method.

If the document does exist you can call `getData` to get at the contents of it.

Answer (score 2):

Task result has a field named AdditionalUserInfo, you can find here isNewUser. it will return false if the user already exists.

```
  if (task.result?.additionalUserInfo!!.isNewUser){
         addNewUser()
    } else {
         updateUser()
  }
```