# how to check if a collection contains certain sub collection or not in firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

i want to make this type of collection in my `firestore`

where `chatRooms` will be my collection name, combination of `myUid and opponentsUid` will be my sub-collection in which different documents will be placed. My problem is i want to check if my collection contains sub-collection named `myUid_opponentsUid` or `opponentsUid_myUid` and i am not able to search a best query for doing this.

All i know is that we can fetch the whole list and then check if it contains the specific room or not, but its a lengthy process, so i want to better method for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check Child Count.! simply.!

Comment: Are you using Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore?  The answer below by @AtifAbbAsi seems to be for RTDB.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few misconceptions in your question to clear up first:

1. In Firestore collections don't really exist as distinct entities. It's the documents inside a collection that cause it to become visible.
2. Also, collections can only contain documents, which in turn can contain collections, but the structure must alternate, so you can't have a collection called chatRooms that contains a collection myUid_opponentUid. Inside chatRooms there must be a document.

So if chat rooms contain messages, a straightforward way to do what you want is to create a document that represents that chatRoom. Then within that create a subcollection for the messages.

If you sort the UIDs before creating the composite chatRoom key you can then test whether or not the chat room exists by using a single `get()`. The structure would look like this:

`chatRooms/(uid-pair)/messages/(message-id)`

Note that you don't actually need to store anything at the `chatRoom/(uid-pair)` level to create children at the `messages` level: you can just create new messages and listen directly.

Comment: `okay, thanks for that information`, i am `new to Firestore` but have worked in Firebase database, so was not clear about that. Let me try that by your way, if done i'll mark it as my answer.

Comment: and can you please tell how to `fetch server time in firestore`.

Comment: You can't fetch server time, exactly, but you can request that the server populate a field with the server time when it writes, e.g. `doc.update({updateTime: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()})`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue.

Comment: the main problem is when trying to check if there is document present or not, it always return not equal to null no matter the document exists or not.

Comment: See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46574380/check-if-user-exists-in-firestore

Comment: I tried the `.exists` method as well but it is not returning the correct answers.

Comment: Please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/46905027/6510301

Answer (score 0):

Try to Read Total Number of child .! Hope this thing may helps you.and if you want to implement your own api then try using `Firebase Functions`..and last thing I want to add is that if You want to add get Count without reading number of child you have to implement one method that getChildCount before storing data and then append them with key like `JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfa`,1` and only read keys and then use comma separator and  you will get your result that this parent contains child or not.?

```
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();

      //You can use the single or the value.. depending if you want to keep track
     String id= UUID.randomUUID().toString();//randomID for task

    Object object=new Object ();      




    public int chidcount(String child){

 string childcount="0";


  //You can use the single or the value.. depending if you want to keep track
 myRef.child(child).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   for (DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

        childcount=snap.getChildrenCount();
        Log.e(snap.getKey(),snap.getChildrenCount() + "");
    }

    addvalue(childcount);

   }

  @Override
 public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
        });

}


private addvalue(String childcount){
 object=setid(id);

     object=setname("name");

      getchildCount("object");

        mdatabaseRef.child("rating").child(manager.getId()+childcount).child(currentEmployee.getId()).child(id).setValue(rating);}
```

Comment: if you have read my question carefully, i have mentioned there that i know that i can fetch the whole list and then check if it contains those values or not, but if the data is huge then it becomes a very lengthy process, that's why i am finding some alternative for it. But thanks for your efforts, if there is some other way then please let me know.

Comment: Firebase function is what you are looking for I think so.! @Anmol

Comment: and one more thing if you want to try it..make a function that get child count every before saving data then add that child count with your parent node key.? like 21736172368,1; and then split it.! and get number of child by only reading keys from firebase.!@Anmol

Comment: `but i dont want to read the child count!` i just want to get `if my collection contains a specific sub-collection or not.`

Comment: You only have to read child count before storing data in firebase database...then after that there is no need to read child out . when retrieving.? @Anmol

Comment: i am not getting your point. how can i check if the collection contains `myUid_OpponentUid` with the help of the count? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late.
Posting for future users.
Try this:

```
DocumentReference datab = db.collection("collection_name").document("Doc_name");


                    datab.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {

                            if(documentSnapshot.contains("field_name"))
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Child exixts.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                            else
                                Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Doesnt exits.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For Firebase Firestore to check whether the document has entries (fields), Use this command

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(userId)
  .addSnapshotListener {
    documentSnapshot, _ ->
        if (documentSnapshot!!.contains("name")) {
            Log.i("Name", "Name exists")
        } else {
            Log.i("Name", "Name doesn't exists")
        }
}
```