# firestore data storing in sub collections

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a "chatting demo" in Firestore for saving messages I am doing it like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    .collection(Consts.R_CHAT_ROOM)
    .document(finalChatRoom)
    .collection("messages")
    .document(currentTime)
    .set(chatModel);
```

But the problem is that the `finalChatRoom` document shows that it does not exist although it contains a subcollection.

[image: database screenshot]

As it's written there: "this document does not exist" although it contains a sub-collection named `messages` in it which contains further documents.

But I need to check if the document with a specific name is present under the `chatRoomsMessages` collection or not.

Is there any problem with my code or do I need to do it in some other way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your new document will be under the `messages` subcollection.

Comment: yes, but i need to check if the `document with a specific name` is present under the `chatRoomsMessages collection` or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a subcollection in a document that does not exist is much like creating a document with a subcollection and then deleting the document. From the [Subcollections section of the Data Model documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections) this means:

> When you delete a document that has associated subcollections, the subcollections are not deleted. They are still accessible by reference. For example, there may be a document referenced by `db.collection('coll').doc('doc').collection('subcoll').doc('subdoc')` even though the document referenced by `db.collection('coll').doc('doc')` no longer exists.

If you want the document to exist, I'd suggest creating the `finalChatRoom` document first, with at least one field, and then creating the subcollection underneath it. For example:

```
DocumentReference chatRoomDocument = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        .collection(Consts.R_CHAT_ROOM)
        .document(finalChatRoom);

// Create the chat room document
ChatRoom chatRoomModel = new ChatRoom("Chat Room 1");
chatRoomDocument.set(chatRoomModel);

// Create the messages subcollection with a new document
chatRoomDocument.collection("messages")
        .document(currentTime).set(chatModel);
```

Where the `ChatRoom` class is something like:

```
public class ChatRoom {
    private String name;

    public ChatRoom() {}

    public ChatRoom(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // ...
}
```

This is making use of the [custom objects functionality of Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects). If you don't want to use a custom object at this stage, you could just create a simple `Map` instead to represent the chat room:

```
Map<String, Object> chatRoomModel = new HashMap<>();
chatRoomModel.put("name", "Chat Room 1");
```

Comment: thanks for your response and it is `really helpful for me to understand things in a better way`, let me just try the way you told me and if everything goes right i'll mark it as answer. Thanks.